# OpenSCAD: Rotating around a particular point?

Tags: openscad

The following code rotates the second cube around the origin.  How can I rotate the second cube around its center point ([5,5,0]) instead?

```
cube([10,10,1]);
rotate([0,0,45]) cube([10,10,1]);
```

[image]

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This module will perform the desired rotation.

```
// rotate as per a, v, but around point pt
module rotate_about_pt(a, v, pt) {
    translate(pt)
        rotate(a,v)
            translate(-pt)
                children();   
}

cube([10,10,1]);
rotate_about_pt(45,0,[5,5,0]) cube([10,10,1]);
```

[image]

In newer versions (tested with the January 2019 preview) the above code generates a warning. To fix that, update the parameters to `rotate`:

```
module rotate_about_pt(z, y, pt) {
    translate(pt)
        rotate([0, y, z]) // CHANGE HERE
            translate(-pt)
                children();   
}
```

Comment: thanks, this really should've be built in to the rotate command

Comment: +1.  This really should be part of the language's syntax.  But thanks for the snippet.  I ended up rewriting it for my purposes to take two array parameters (the three axis rotation amounts and the point), but it saved me a decent chunk of time having that as a starting point.

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to 'center' the shape it is much easier:

```
cube(center =true,[10,10,1]);
rotate([0,0,45]) cube(center =true,[10,10,1]);
```

Comment: That only works with primitives that have that option.